# Is there a way to make a repeating command block not apply its command to server operators?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a radius that players are turned into adventure mode, but when they leave they get turned back into survival, the part I cannot figure out is how to make it so server operators are not affected by this (and/or a list of players too).

These are the commands that I have in 2 separate repeating command blocks:

```
/gamemode survival @a[distance=30..]

/gamemode adventure @a[distance=..28]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to tag all players who are op with `tag <name> add op`. Then, those two commands can be `gamemode survival @a[distance=30..,tag=!op]` and `gamemode adventure @a[distance=..28,tag=!op]`. `tag=!op` will affect all players who are not tagged with the tag "op".

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple of these in one world?

Comment: If you want to have multiple areas where op players are not affected by commands this will work, as long as the selectors for the commands all contain `tag=!op`. This is because tags are global, meaning a player with a tag will have it until someone removes it or their server data is erased. Because you have to tag them manually, you can also make custom lists arbitrarily of players who you want to exempt from being affected by commands. Just use a different tag, like "exempt" or something.

Comment: *clarification* Would multiple zones of "within this radius you are in adventure mode", interfere with one another?

Comment: Sorry, I generalized it too much. Multiple command blocks like those above in different areas of the map would work, but you would need to change the one with 30.. to 30..32, maybe, so that on their way out players are changed into survival mode. Otherwise, as you noticed, they would interfere with each other. Alternatively, give each area it's own tag, like op1, op2, op3... but the detriment of this is that you have to tag every op player with all of the op# tags.